# Httpie auth plugin issues POST Request FORMAT

Tags: authentication, httpie

POST JSON body doesnt work with these plugins and have opened issues. Same POST Syntax I have successfully used with oauth, ntlm etc

1. HAWK
   echo '{"hello": "world"}' | http POST http://localhost:8080/ --auth-type=hawk --auth 'username:password'
   Error: http: error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
   Opened issue: https://github.com/mozilla-services/requests-hawk/issues/26
2. HMAC
   echo '{"hello": "world"}' | http POST http://localhost:8080/ --auth-type=hmac --auth 'username:password'
   http: error: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found
   Opened Issue: https://github.com/guardian/httpie-hmac-auth/issues/5
3. HTTPIE
   echo '{"hello": "world"}' | http POST http://localhost:8080/ --auth-type=httpsig --auth 'username:password'
   http: error: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
   Opened Issue: https://github.com/east36/httpie-http-signatures/issues/5

Comment: Plugins should not have impact on the syntax. So it’s an error on their part. Please open an issue in the HTTPie repo and I’ll see if I can fix them myself: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Those issues should be fixed with:

1. requests-hawk: [PR #32](https://github.com/mozilla-services/requests-hawk/pull/32)
2. httpie-http-signatures: [PR #6](https://github.com/east36/httpie-http-signatures/pull/6)
3. httpie-hmac-auth: [PR #6](https://github.com/guardian/httpie-hmac-auth/pull/6)